# I want to do 301 redirect but it's going wrong

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect user to 404 page on wrong url, but it end up redirecting from all pages. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule . /404.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't "redirect" to an error document. You should instead configure a custom error document using the `ErrorDocument` directive, then Apache will respond with the `404.php` using an internal subrequest and ensure the correct HTTP status is set (ie. a 404, not a 301).

Your condition that checks the existence of the `.php` file (prior to rewriting) is not strictly correct, depending on the URL-path being requested. `REQUEST_FILENAME` contains the filesystem path that the request maps to, which is not necessarily the same as the URL-path being requested.

Try the following instead, assuming your `.htaccess` file is in the document root:

```
# Define custom error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on 

# Rewrite - append .php extension if required.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```